# www.mysite.com or mysite.com are different... help!

Tags: website, flash, embedded

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [www not present in some websites](https://superuser.com/questions/62666/www-not-present-in-some-websites)

I have a flash movie that I am embedding on mysite.com
the domain i have registered is 
mysite.com
what I don't understand is why I can't view the exact same page and load the same information on 
www.mysite.com
?

Do I need to go into my control panel and enable something?
Pay more money?
Re-direct?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: This has been answered about a billion times already. Please use the search function. It is also probably more suited to be asked on serverfault anyway.

Comment: ok; i would love to 'mark' your answer as the accepted answer, but you didn't post it as an answer.  hope that you have a good night and thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is down to DNS.

This is dependent on your host, and you may want to ask them for help if you haven't done it before.

Basically, you need to set a record in the `mysite.com zone` called `www`, make it a `Cname` with a value of `mysite.com`.

If you do not have an option just to create a cname, then try creating a record for `WWW.mysite.com` anyway you can and put the same value (ip) in for it as you do for the main non-www address.

You also need to set host headers up on the web server, but this really should of already been done.

Comment: +1 for the excellent answer: But they'd be creating the host record named just "WWW" for the zone/domain named "mysite.com".  Else it'd be "www.mysite.com.mysite.com" ;)

Comment: ahh... +1, you are correct - missed that!... I don't know how mass hosting works, would they have a zone for each .com, or just have it all in one .com zone :S... anyway, you are correct!

Comment: Right on the money. +1.